# radio buttons selected values is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have tried to select radio button from selected value of a drop down like this

```
    Dim ddlupd As DropDownList = CType(grid.HeaderRow.FindControl("dropdown"), DropDownList)
        For Each gv As GridViewRow In grid.Rows
            Dim rdo As RadioButtonList = CType(grid.Rows(gv.RowIndex).FindControl("list"), RadioButtonList)
            Dim cat As Label = CType(grid.Rows(gv.RowIndex).FindControl("lblcat"), Label)
            If cat.Text = ddlupd.SelectedItem.Text Then
                rdo.SelectedValue = selflg.ToString()
            ElseIf ddlupd.SelectedItem.Text = "Clear Selection" Then
                rdo.ClearSelection()
            ElseIf ddlupd.SelectedItem.Text = "Select All" Then
                rdo.SelectedValue = selflg.ToString()
            End If
        Next
```

and there is template field in gridview like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlupdGM1" BackColor="#3399FF" ForeColor="White">
             <asp:ListItem>Select Category</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Clear Selection</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="1">Cane Payment</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="2">Income Tax</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="3">Fund Transfer</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="4">Others</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:RadioButtonList ID="chkStatusGM" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkStatus_OnCheckedChangedGM">
             <asp:ListItem Value="5">Approve</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="0">Not Approved</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Also I Am running a update command to database with selected values of radio button.Problem is that when select the radio button from drop down value of header template then no update runs due to null selection of radiobutton and when i manually select the radio button the update works fine.

**Update** 
**

```
Protected Sub chkStatus_OnCheckedChangedGM(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()

        Dim chkStatusGM As RadioButtonList = CType(sender, RadioButtonList)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(chkStatusGM.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim bpvnum As String = row.Cells(4).Text

        cmd.CommandText = "update sml.FND_01_11@wbg set sta_flg=:sta_flg where bpv_num=:bpv_num and bpv_dte=:bpv_dte"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.Parameters.Add(":sta_flg", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = chkStatusGM.SelectedValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":bpv_num", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = bpvnum
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":bpv_dte", OleDbType.Date).Value = TreeView2.SelectedValue
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the SelectedIndexChanged event of the radio button list (or whatever event handler you are using):

```
Dim ddlupd As DropDownList = CType(grid.HeaderRow.FindControl("dropdown"), DropDownList)
    For Each gv As GridViewRow In grid.Rows
        Dim rdo As RadioButtonList = CType(grid.Rows(gv.RowIndex).FindControl("list"), RadioButtonList)
        Dim cat As Label = CType(grid.Rows(gv.RowIndex).FindControl("lblcat"), Label)
        If cat.Text = ddlupd.SelectedItem.Text Then
            rdo.SelectedValue = selflg.ToString()
        ElseIf ddlupd.SelectedItem.Text = "Clear Selection" Then
            rdo.ClearSelection()
        ElseIf ddlupd.SelectedItem.Text = "Select All" Then
            rdo.SelectedValue = selflg.ToString()
        End If

        ' call the event handler similar to manually clicking an option
        chkStatus_OnCheckedChangedGM(rdo, new System.EventArgs())
    Next
```

Comment: Sir O Got this error `BC32022: 'Public Event SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.`

Comment: I updated my answer.  You should call the name of your event handler, not the event itself as my original answer stupidly suggested.  Hope this helps.

Comment: do u mean i should call this `chkStatus_OnCheckedChangedGM` on radiolist inside gridivew

Comment: this give error in the event `chkStatus_OnCheckedChangedGM` error is `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Post your code for the the chkStatus_OnCheckedChangedGM method.  You may have to call that with the selected item, e.g., `Call chkStatus_OnCheckedChangedGM(rdo, new eventargs())`

Comment: I updated my answer in which i show rdo event which show error on this line `Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(chkStatusGM.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)`

Comment: Yes, you were looking for the sender, which is reasonable.  My updated answer should fix the error.

Comment: Sir can u tell Me Why the value of rdo changes for update with out calling `chkStatus_OnCheckedChangedGM(rdo, new System.EventArgs())`? Beacuse i have to often change the value of rdo after selection then want to update the DB

Comment: The concept of an event fired by a UI control is that the user interacted with it.  If you are setting values in the code behind, the user didn't initiate the event, it was done programmatically.  That being said, code-behind events do exist, but in this case it they don't fire because the UI was not interacted with by the user.

Comment: For better programming design, you should create a function elsewhere that is called 1) when the onSelectedIndexChanged event fires, and 2) when you change this value in code.  That will help your code make sense, so you can see "UpdateSelectedItems(rdo)" in your code rather than calling the event handler.  Get it working first, though, before you start changing the design.